imperative apex call not pulling the latest data
I have an LWC component that updates the fields of some work order line items. Then I did a SOQL on developer console to confirm if the values were updated.
Now I have another LWC component that will work on the same set of data on a button click.
Here I am doing an imperative call to get the updated values and for some reason what I am getting is old values before the update performed by the first LWC component.
Here is the Controller method -
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<WorkOrderLineItem> getWorkOrderLineItemsByWorkOrderId(String workOrderId) {
    return [
        SELECT Id, 
        Item_Number__c,
        Item_Quantity__c,      
        FROM WorkOrderLineItem
        WHERE WorkOrderId = :workOrderId
    ];
}

Here is how I am calling the above apex method from LWC. The console statement inside prints the old values.
import getWorkOrderLineItemsByWorkOrderId from '@salesforce/apex/ApexUtilitiesController.getWorkOrderLineItemsByWorkOrderId';

applyChangesToWorkOrderLineItems(event) {
        this.showAlertModal = false;
        console.log('event.detail.source: ' + event.detail.source);
        if (event.detail.source === 'yes') {
            this.workOrderLineItemRecordsToUpdate = [];
            this.workOrderLineItemRecordsToCreate = [];

            getWorkOrderLineItemsByWorkOrderId({ workOrderId: this.recordId }).then(result => {
                this.workOrderLineItemRecords = result;
                console.log('workOrderLineItemRecords: ' + JSON.stringify(this.workOrderLineItemRecords)); //This does not print the latest updated values.

            })
        }
    }

This is what I have tried. Somewhere I read the @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) was causing the issue. Then I tried the apex method with just AuraEnabled attribute that also didn't pull the updated values.

It is the cachable=true causing the problem. Make sure you actually successfully deployed the updated apex. There's a chance you might need to also clear session caching to immediately see the change in behaviour.

@PhilW when I removed cacheable=true I noticed the other LWC components using the same apex method was not pulling any data. So did you mean to create another apex method that does the same thing for this specific scenario with not cacheable=true? Also when you mentioned to clear session caching did you mean to turn off this setting - Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance under session settings in setup?


If you have other components using the same method from a wire (for example) and you want the values to be cached in those components, you'll want to have two "versions" of the method (with the required @AuraEnabled annotations, one cacheable=true the other not, and having different names to allow the components to reference the right one) that call through to a common method that actually does the query - don't duplicate the code. 2. Yes, that's what I meant. Only needed while you make the change. You should be able to turn it back on again soon thereafter.


Thanks @PhilW. Can you put it as an answer please?

The fundamental problem is the use of cacheable=true. This means that the Apex won't be called every time the JavaScript invokes it. When the calls are within a certain amount of time of each other a client side case is used, meaning the previously returned value may be given back to the JavaScript code without making a call to the org.
If this is the only use of that Apex, removing the cacheable=true and calling the method imperatively from your JavaScript results in the Apex being called every time the imperative call is made.
If you have other components using the same method from a wire and you want the values to be cached in those components (wires require this of course), you'll want to have two "versions" of the method (with the required @AuraEnabled annotations, one cacheable=true the other not, and having different names to allow the components to reference the right one) that call through to a common method that actually does the query - don't duplicate the code.
NB: There's a chance that the old behaviour will persist in the browser until your current session expires, if "Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance" is turned on in Session Settings (this is the default). You may need to temporarily disable this caching.
